# Can proton NMR be used to study transition metal complexes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, nmr-spectroscopy

I prepared metal complexes with a Schiff base ligand L using cobalt(II) chloride hexahydrate, iron(III) chloride hexahydrate, and nickel(II) nitrate hexahydrate. I used <sup>1</sup>H NMR to study the difference between them and maybe get some information about the structure of the formed complexes.

The results showed a slight upfield shift in almost every peak and the appearance of some new peaks (attached figure), which is a bit ambiguous for me, and I don't know how to interpret them:

[image]

Comment: Please be more precise ! Which Schiff base do you use ? Please describe the positions of the peaks and their intensity. Without any numerical values, we cannot help you.

Comment: Dear @Maurice, thanks for the recommendation. I added a figure, I hope its helpful.